# Button not showing in Angular 4

Tags: angular, firebase

Im creating an user profile component and I want the user to be able to update his own profile. What I m trying to do is that the button should be disabled until the user changes something in his profile. The problem is that the button is not showing even when the user changes his profile.

Thanks for your help guys!

userprofile.component.html

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(userProfileForm)"
      #userProfileForm="ngForm"
      fxFlexFill [fxLayout]="'row'"
      fxLayoutAlign="center start">
<div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <strong>Company</strong>
          <small>Form</small>
        </div>
        <div class="card-block">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="company">{{user.profile.displayName}}</label>
            <input type="text" id="company"
                  fxFlex="100"
                  required
                  minlength="3"
                  placeholder="Username"
                  [(ngModel)]="user.profile.username"
                  name="username"
                  #username="ngModel">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="vat">VAT</label>
            <input type="text" id="vat"
              fxFlex="100"
               minlength="3"
               placeholder="Display Name"
               [(ngModel)]="user.profile.displayName"
               name="displayName"
               #displayName="ngModel">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="street">Street</label>
            <input type="text" id="street" placeholder="Enter street name">
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-8">
              <label for="city">City</label>
              <input type="text" id="city" placeholder="Enter your city">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
              <label for="postal-code">Postal Code</label>
              <input type="text" id="postal-code" placeholder="Postal Code">
            </div>
          </div><!--/.row-->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="country">Country</label>
            <input type="text" id="country" placeholder="Country name">
          </div>
          <button type="submit"
              [disabled]="!userProfileForm.form.valid || !profileIsChanged()">
      </button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

userprofile.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import {UserService} from "../pages/users/user.service";
import {User} from "../pages/users/user";
import {Profile} from "../pages/users/profile";
import {AuthService} from "../pages/login/auth.service";
import {MdSnackBar} from "@angular/material";
import {Observable, Subscription} from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-userprofile',
  templateUrl: './userprofile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./userprofile.component.scss']
})
export class UserprofileComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

   initialProfile: Profile;
  user: User;

  error: string;
  private sub: any;

  constructor(private userService: UserService,
    private auth: AuthService,
    public updateValidationBar: MdSnackBar) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let sub = this.auth.currentUser().subscribe(user => {
      this.user = user;
      this.cloneInitial(this.user.profile);
    });
    this.user = new User();
    this.user.profile = new Profile();
    this.cloneInitial(this.user.profile);
  }



  cloneInitial(profile : Profile){
    this.initialProfile = Object.assign(new Profile(), profile);
  }

  onSubmit(userProfileForm){
    if(userProfileForm.form.valid){
      let sub = this.userService.updateUserProfile(this.user)
        .subscribe(user => {
          this.updateValidationBar.open("Your profile is update", "Ok", {
            duration: 3000
          });
          this.cloneInitial(user.profile);
        },
        err => {
          this.error = err.message;
        },
        () => {
         ;
        });
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }


  profileIsChanged(){
    return this.user.profile.displayName !== this.initialProfile.displayName
      || this.user.profile.username !== this.initialProfile.username
      || this.user.profile.email !== this.initialProfile.email;
  }
}
```

EDIT! Im an idiot. I didnt put any content in the button! Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Did you not put any text content in the button on purpose?

Comment: Good one :) - maybe there is a CSS content property

Comment: @peeskillet Im an idiot. It was working but not showing because the button didnt appear because it had no content and it was blending with the background. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`[disabled]="!userProfileForm.form.valid || !profileIsChanged()"` to
`[disabled]="!userProfileForm.valid || !profileIsChanged()"`
+ add value between  tags

works?

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
[disabled]="!userProfileForm.dirty"
```

Please provide the end tag of  in your html.

If you want to use email, include email as a field inside form and include ngModel property.